# classes in same package not see each others and not compiled in terminal

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, terminal, compilation

```
package mainPackage

public class MainClass{

  Public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invoikeLater(new Runnable()){
        Login login = new Login();
    }
  }
}
```

both classes ( MainClass & Login ) at the same package (mainPackage).

On netbeans IDE the application works fine (compile & execute ).

But when using Terminal to compile MainClass I get this error :

error: cannot find symbol

```
            Login login= new Login();
            ^
```

symbol: class Login

here is my directory :

/home/momy/application

```
|
src
    |
    mainPackage
        |
        MainClass.java
        Login.java
```

To compile code:

```
application$ javac  src/mainPackage/MainClass.java
```

any idea why?

Comment: Are you compiling both at the same time? Are both source files in the same directory named `mainPackage`? Are you sure you are in the directory above that one when issue the `javac` command??

Comment: what is the exact path from which you invoke  `javac`?

Comment: `Package mainPackage` that keyword is `package` (no capital letters).

Comment: *"I added the details.."* What 'details'? Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @RealSkeptic (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Again, read the tip of @AndrewThompson (add an `@` before his name to get him notified). Also please post where are you located in your terminal while compiling. What happens if you go to `mainPackage`? And correct the `Package` word for `package` (lower case "P")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
application$ javac  src/mainPackage/MainClass.java
```

The problem is here. You should be in the `src` directory:

```
application/src$ javac  mainPackage/MainClass.java
```